Next.js server-only Wrapper
I'm using Next in a monorepo. It pulls data from a package with some shared business logic. I'd like to make sure that business logic remains on the server. My understanding is that import 'server-only' is the correct way to do that. I'd rather not add the import to each file in my shared package, and was hoping to avoid writing getter methods in a server-only file in the Next repo. The solution I came up with is to write a file containing the following:
// ServerOnly.ts
import 'server-only'
export default function <T>(exec: () => T) {
    return exec()
}

and then in my pages retrieve the data like so
// page.tsx
import ServerOnly from "@/app/ServerOnly"

export default async function Page() {
    const {data} = await ServerOnly(async () => {
        const data = //...some business logic
        return { data }
    })
    return (
        <ClientPage data={data}/>
    )
}

The code runs without issue, but I want to make sure that the above will actually enforce the server-only restriction.
Thanks!
